# Hijack React handler function

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I’m trying to hijack all button handlers from a global method and manually trigger the handler if a certain condition is met. A simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zvy80mpf/

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // Button
    // I want to hijack the component handler here and trigger it manually
}

var Hello = React.createClass({
    handler: function() {
        console.log('component onclick');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>
                <button handler={this.handler}>Hello</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Hello clickHandler={clickHandler} />, document.body);
```

I know I can pass the `handler` function, but I want to access the handlers from a global context, without modifying the internal components.

In jQuery you can do that using `$._data(element, 'events')`, is there a similar way in React?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to totally understand what you ask for but...

There is an undocumented way in React to pass data to a whole hierarchy of sub components.

You can for exemple use the following:

```
React.withContext({handler: handler},function() {
        React.renderComponent(
            self.mountComponent(props),
            self.mountNode
        );
    });
```

And then you can access the handler in all subcomponents with a Mixin like:

```
var WithHandlerMixin = {
    contextTypes: {
        handler: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },
    getHandler(): function() {
        return this.context.handler;
    }
};
```

This is undocumented because it is considered as unstable by the React team and may have some bugs. But from my experience, using simple code like that works fine and is already used by some popular React frameworks like `Fluxxor` without any trouble. Just be aware that the signatures may change, but the React team told me the feature won't be removed.

You have however to modify all the components accessing that handler, but a mixin is not so intrusive I guess.

Comment: Interesting. I was more interested in accessing handlers based on a DOM Node (or a reference to a component), but this way might work too

Answer (score -1):

if you bind your gobal handler to "this" in your component, you should be able to call the component click-handler from the global function, like this:

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // Button
    // Hijack the component onClick here
    this.handler();
}

var Hello = React.createClass({
    handler: function() {
        console.log('component onclick');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler.bind(this)}> 
                <button handler={this.onClick}>Hello</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Hello clickHandler={clickHandler} />, document.body);
```